# How is “for(const [[[[[a, b, c]]]]] in [0, 0]);” even valid?

Tags: javascript

Writing dumb code, I've just found something weird.

```js
for(const [[[[[fancy, loop]]]]] in [0, 0]) {
  console.log(fancy, loop);
}
```

```
// Chrome 70.0.3538.77 says:
// 0 undefined
// 1 undefined
```

It's like assigning `0` and `1` to `[[[[[fancy, loop]]]]]`, which, is *array destructurings* taking place and supposed to throw an error, isn't it? Or not. It's just my thought getting me confused right now.

Could you please tell me how it is valid and works with no error? What am I missing?

Comment: @RobG Yeah, but, how could it destructure `0` and `1`?

Comment: you can always throw the code into a transpiler to see what is happening

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYewTgFAxiB2DOAXABAbXe4BDWUCeANMgDYggAOAutdcgJaxoAMRTlAlMgN4BQyyMBCGIBTAHSkA5hGy5CJMuXYBuHgF8eQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-3%2Cenv&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2

Comment: I guess you discovered a new question for javascript job interviews. ;-)

Comment: ^ @RobG for anyone wondering, this should be taken as sarcasm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not assigning `0` and `1` to `[[[[[fancy, loop]]]]]`. You're looping over the keys of `[0, 0]`, because you used `in` instead of `of`, and those keys are *strings*.

The string `"0"` is an iterable whose sole element is `"0"`. Assigning `"0"` to `[[[[[fancy, loop]]]]]` repeatedly unpacks `"0"` and gets `"0"`, until eventually it gets down to

```
[fancy, loop] = "0"
```

at which point the final unpacking assigns `"0"` to `fancy` and `undefined` to `loop`.

Comment: This doesn't fully explain what is occurring though, there is a difference between `[fancy, loop]` and `[[fancy, loop]]` given `[,,,,,,,,,0,0]` (i.e. try it with property names of more than one character). The assignments are different so it doesn't simply reduce to `[fancy, loop]`.

Comment: @RobG: You skipped the first four layers of unpacking, each of which only takes one element. `"10"` gets unpacked into `"1"` and `"0"`, and the `"0"` gets discarded in the first layer of the destructuring assignment. By the time we hit the `[fancy, loop]` unpacking, the `"0"` has been gone for the last three layers.

Comment: Yes, that's the missing part. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You're using `in` instead of  `of` so you're getting the properties of the array not the values. For this case you're getting the array indexes as strings (`0`, `1`). You're basically destructuring a string with length of 1 every time. So you always get the first character of every iterated property